# Creating sequential ID in panda dataframe for given column values

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create a unique sequential ID for each given values in the "Type" column but can't seem to make it work.

Current data frame:

```
    Item    Type    ID
0   Apple   Fruit   0
1   Orange  Fruit   1
2   Banana  Fruit   2
3   Peach   Fruit   3
4   Cheese  Dairy   0
5   Milk    Dairy   1
6   Chicken Meat    0
7   Pork    Meat    1
8   Beef    Meat    2
```

Desired data frame:

```
    Item    Type    ID
0   Apple   Fruit   0
1   Orange  Fruit   1
2   Banana  Fruit   2
3   Peach   Fruit   3
4   Cheese  Dairy   0
5   Milk    Dairy   1
6   Chicken Meat    0
7   Pork    Meat    1
8   Beef    Meat    2
```

I've tried to set_index and creating a separate column that indicating "Type" value change but was not able to create the desired format. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post your dataframe directly rather than the image of it. Besides, how do you want to handle in case of identical _Item_?

Comment: Sorry Chris, the images didn't come out as expected. I will post the data frame directly. Tawab_Shakeel solved my problem below. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

try using cumcount()

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"Type":["Fruit","Fruit","Dairy","Meat","Meat"],
                        "Item":["Apple","Orange","Chesse","Pork","Beef"]})

df["ID"] = df.groupby(['Type']).cumcount()
print(df)
```

```
    Type    Item  ID
0  Fruit   Apple   0
1  Fruit  Orange   1
2  Dairy  Chesse   0
3   Meat    Pork   0
4   Meat    Beef   1
```

I hope it would solve your problem

Comment: I was about to post a (more cumbersome) solution with `cumsum`, didn't know `cumcount` - thanks!

Comment: Exactly what I need. THANK YOU tawab_shakeel!!!!

Comment: @sangurocactus approve it or upvote if you found it helpful